# Generalization of G-delta Sets

Tags: general-topology, second-countable

A $G_\delta$-set is obtained from a countable intersection of open sets. Do we have any results about the intersection of *uncountably* many open sets? Or does it even make sense?

The $G_\delta$-sets arise naturally from considering the $\sigma$-algebra generated by the usual topology on the real line and I assume that this is how the $G_\delta$-sets are motivated. But what if we look at larger structures (meaning with cardinalities larger than the continuum) equipped with a topology that is, for example, not second-countable and so any basis is also necessarily large? The $G_\delta$-sets would form a smaller family compared to the family of sets formed by the intersections of say $\aleph_1$ open sets each, wouldn't they?

In any case, please enlighten me on the subject. I am unfamiliar.

Comment: Assuming you also generalize $F_\sigma$ in the same way, any useful formulation is likely to stumble across a subset of the Borel Algebra

Comment: @brevan-ellefsen the Borel algebra only makes use of *countable* unions and intersections, which is different from the OP's suggestion.

Comment: @J.-E.Pin In each stage of its construction yes, but remember it uses transfinite induction. One can easily show the Borel Algebra over $\mathbb R$ contains sets that cannot be formed via countable union and intersection; the root cause is that we must induct at least up to the first uncountable ordinal

Comment: @J.-E.Pin Formally, the Borel algebra is the result of iterating $G \mapsto G_{\delta \sigma}$ up to the first uncountable ordinal. Informally, we think of the Borel Algebra as being the union of $G_x$ where $x$ is any small enough but possibly uncountable family of $\sigma$s and $\delta$s

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In any  Hausdorff topological space (in particular in a metric space) any subset is a union of singleton sets (which are closed). Hence, by taking complements,  every subset is an intersection of open sets.

Comment: Ahh, but not all sets is a countable intersection of open sets. That's why it's interesting to look at the countable intersections. I see!